# How to handle routing in laravel modular application

Tags: php, laravel, module, routes

I know there are question/answer for routing in modules. But i have tried all that but i can't get any workaround.

Let me show what i have done.

My folder structure

[image]

My ModuleServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Modules;

class ModulesServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Will make sure that the required modules have been fully loaded
     * @return void
     */

    public function boot()
    {

        if ($module = $this->getModule(func_get_args())) {
             include __DIR__.'/'.$module.'/routes.php';
        }
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/Views', 'core');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        if ($module = $this->getModule(func_get_args())) {

        }
    }

    public function getModule($args)
    {
        $module = (isset($args[0]) and is_string($args[0])) ? $args[0] : null;

        return $module;
    }
}
```

My BlogServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Modules\Blog;

class BlogServiceProvider extends \App\Modules\ModulesServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        parent::register('Blog');
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot('Blog');
    }
}
```

in app\config\app.php

`'App\Modules\Blog\BlogServiceProvider',` //added in providers array

in app\config

module.php created

```
return  [
    'modules' => [
       'Blog',
    ]
];
```

in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/Modules"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
             "Modules\\": "Modules/"
        }
    },
```

Everything seems perfect but in i trapped in routes.

in my app\Modules\Blog\routes.php

```
    Route::group(['namespace' => array('Modules\Blog')], function() {
      Route::get('/',['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'PostController@index']);
    });
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'App\Modules\Blog\Controllers\PostController@index']);
```

I m getting PostController doesn't exist error

My controller namespace

```
 namespace App\Modules\Blog\Controllers;
```

I am getting that error on both route. whether i specify controller path or not. any help please. How to route in modular application.

Comment: I think this line on your composer.json: `"Modules\\": "Modules/"` should be `"Modules\\": "app/Modules/"`instead. And don't forget to do `composer dump-autoload`. Edit: see @Ruffles answer. You already have the Modules folder inside app/.

Comment: As per documentation of laravel-modules, it is instructed to have Modules directory as a sibling of app directory, not its child. Coz the default configurations of the namespaces in the modules is set to derive that way and changing it shall result in specifying custom namespaces to each module in its configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the namespace in the route group from `['namespace' => array('Modules\Blog')]` to `['namespace' => 'App\Modules\Blog\Controllers']` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

**1** Edit your composer.json file and correct your prs-4 autoload to:

```
 "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Modules\\": "app/Modules/"
  }
```

**2** update the namespaces of your files by removing the "App\" 
and  **3** do a composer dump-autoload

Comment: That works but when i write `Route::get('new-post',['as' => 'homenew', 'uses' => 'App\Modules\Blog\Controllers\PostController@create']);`. That give me error requested page doesn't work.

Comment: Try    'uses' => '\Modules\Blog\Controllers\PostController@create'])

Answer (score 0):

Go to the map method on your RouteServiceProvider. You can tell laravel to load your routes depending on the namespace.

```
$router->group(['namespace' => 'App\Controllers'], function ($router)   {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });

$router->group(['namespace' => 'App\Modules\MyModuleControllers'], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Modules/MyModule/routes.php');
    });
```

Comment: not working. do we need to define same route in parent app\Http\route.php? If i use same route in  app\Http\route.php this works. but in Blog\routes.php not working

Comment: here we're telling laravel to look at the route and load the appropriate controller class. If you have multiple namespaces (multiple modules) you will need to loop them and call this multiple times. no need to define the same routes in the main routes.php. you problem must be with namespace not resolving correctly. before checking the route make sure the blog module class namespace can be resolved.

Comment: don't know what is wrong. but when  add `require_once base_path()."/app/Modules/Blog/routes.php"` in main route.php. it works.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solution by this. i changed ModuleServiceProvider

```
namespace App\Modules;

class ModulesServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Will make sure that the required modules have been fully loaded
     * @return void
     */

    public function boot()
    {

        if ($module = $this->getModule(func_get_args())) {
             require_once __DIR__.'/'.$module.'/routes.php';
        }
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/Views', 'core');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        if ($module = $this->getModule(func_get_args())) {

        }
    }

    public function getModule($args)
    {
        $module = (isset($args[0]) and is_string($args[0])) ? $args[0] : null;

        return $module;
    }
}
```

I replaced `require_once` instead of `include` in `boot` function. And its working.

In route i am giving

```
Route::get('new-post',['uses' => 'App\Modules\Blog\Controllers\PostController@create']);
```

Hope it helps others !!

Answer (score -1):

Look this package,

- [Pingpong Module](https://github.com/pingpong-labs/modules)
- [Caffeinated Module](https://github.com/caffeinated/modules)